# ReactJS - Updating a component who requires an API call without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my main page component, which I can get my products informations from my API.

Everything is working, but now I have another component called updateProducts with another feature where I can update my products price. And right after this update, I need to fetch my products informations again without refreshing the page.

**I came up with this and everything is working the way I want, but I don't know if this is the proper way of doing it.**

Code below:

**Main component that fetch the data from my API:**

```
export default function MainComponent() {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  // I created this new state and I'm passing the setState as a props to my updatePrice component
  const [productsCallback, setProductsCallback] = useState("")

  // Fetching the data from my API
  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const { data: { rows } } = await api.get(`/community/${id}/product`)
        setProducts(rows)

      } catch (error) {
        toast.error('Failed to fetch data from the server.')
      }
    }
    getProducts()
  // everytime productsCallback changes, I'll get the data from my API
  }, [productsCallback])
}

// Passing the setState as a prop
<UpdatePrice
  setProductsCallback={() => setProductsCallback(Math.random())}
/>
```

**UpdatePrice component:**

```
export default function UpdatePrice({ setProductsCallback }) {

  function updateProductPrice() {
    updateProductAction(id, price)
    // Right after the product price is updated, the productsCallback state is
    // also changed, and my API is going to fetch the data again, with is exactly what I need.
    setProductsCallback()
  }
}
```

And what if I need to do exactly like this, but my updatePrice component was like 2 or 3 components away from my mainComponent? Instead of passing the setState props from component to component, what is the best way of doing this?

Comment: If you want to avoid prop drilling you could use useContext or Redux

Comment: hey @Skoltz I'm already using redux, but in this particular case, what is the proper way of doing this kind of procedure? Because I'm passing a function as a prop. And do I really need to use the useContext and create a new context just for doing this kind of thing? There is no optimal way of doing this?

Comment: I think using a callback function is fine. However, I would use a boolean variable that I flip each time the Product price is updated instead of the `Math.random()`.